# Cloud Function デプロイエラー

Tags: google-cloud

CloudFunctions にてnode.jsの関数デプロイ時に原因不明のエラーが発生しています。
経緯、状態などは以下に記載しますが、デプロイに失敗した関数の削除すらできず、非常に困惑しています。
成功する環境と失敗する環境があり、ユーザの権限に問題があるかとも思いましたがどちらの環境も操作者はプロジェクトオーナーであり、
問題はないように思います。
似たような状況になった方、解決策をご存じの方いらっしゃいませんでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします

### 経緯

- 自作のCloudFunctions のnode.js関数をテスト環境にて作成/テストし、成功したため本番環境に適用を試みた
- デプロイに失敗し、かつ関数の削除も行えなくなった
- 関数コードの原因を疑い、新たに関数作成し、デフォルト表示されるhelloWorldコードのままデプロイ実施
- やはりデプロイ失敗、かつ削除不能

### 各環境情報

- ログインユーザのロール

  - 本番/テスト環境ともにプロジェクトオーナー
- CloudStrageにソースが保存されているか

  - gcs-sources-**********-asia-northeast1 バケットのzip配置を確認
- CloudFunctions関数設定

  - 関数名：sample
  - リージョン：asia-northeast1
  - トリガータイプ：HTTP
  - 認証：未認証の呼び出しを許可
  - HTTPS：必須
  - 割り当てメモリ：256MB
  - ランタイムサービスアカウント：App Engine default service account
  - 接続：全てのトラフィックを許可する
  - ランタイム：Node.js 16

### デプロイ時エラー

- コンソールヘッダー部通知ドロップダウンに表示されるエラー

  ```
  Cloud Functions の関数「sample」のデプロイ
  {project_id}
  不明なエラーです
  再試行
  ```
- ログエクスプローラ上のエラーログ

  ```
  {
    "protoPayload": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
      "status": {
        "code": 13
      },
      "authenticationInfo": {
        "principalEmail": ******.*@*************.co.jp
      },
      "serviceName": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
      "methodName": "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.CreateFunction",
      "resourceName": "projects/{project_id}/locations/asia-northeast1/functions/sample"
    },
    "insertId": "********",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_function",
      "labels": {
        "region": "asia-northeast1",
        "project_id": "{project_id}",
        "function_name": "sample"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2021-12-16T07:25:27.237827Z",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "logName": "projects/{project_id}/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
    "operation": {
      "id": "operations/**********************************************",
      "producer": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
      "last": true
    },
    "receiveTimestamp": "2021-12-16T07:25:28.223523864Z"
  }
  ```
- 通知一覧で「再試行」クリック時のエラー

  - 通知エリア内での表示

    ```
    Cloud Functions の関数「sample」のデプロイ
    {project_id}
    Function sample in region asia-northeast-1 in puroject {project_id} already exists.
    再試行
    ```

### 現象のよく似たエラーについて記載したドキュメント

- https://coderedirect.com/questions/672727/delete-a-firebase-cloud-function-which-failed-with-deploy-error-undefined

  - 関数の記載内容やnpm依存関係に原因があるように読めるが、それであるなら別環境にて成功することはないと思われる